# How does the JdbcBatchItemWriter decide the batch size?

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-batch, batch-updates, itemwriter

I was going through the documentation of the [JdbcBatchItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcBatchItemWriter.html) but noticed that there is no way of specifying the *batch-size* to use for the `jdbcTemplate` used by this class.  I thought a class that has the name `Batch` in it would have some mechanism to specify the batch size but looks like this is not the case. I now have the following questions regarding determination of batch-size :

1. Is the batch-size equivalent to the commit-interval?
2. If no, does the batch-size get calculated automatically by the framework?

Last but not the least,, is there a way to **explicitly specify the batch-size** to be used by the **`jdbcTemplate`** in the **`JdbcBatchItemWriter`**  while defining the bean for the `JdbcBatchItemWriter` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commit (or batch size) will include all items in the chunk, which is governed by the `commit-interval`. So for all intents and purposes you can treat commit-interval as batch-size.

One caveat to the statement above: your final chunk may have less items than your commit-interval. Additionally if you filter any records using an ItemProcessor, the count of items passed to your Writer would be lower than your commit-interval. Finally, there are also some  custom `CompletionPolicy` scenarios that may result in a commit with more (or less) items than your commit-interval.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great and useful insights! Only one aspect of my question remains unanswered i.e, how do I provide a custom batch size to the JdbcBatchItemWriter? My processor returns a List by converting one line from an input file to many output objects. So a single line in the input file is broken down into a `List` of output objects by the processor and sent to the writer. I don't want the commit-interval of the step to govern the DB insert batch size since 1 input row equals tens of thousands of output rows to be written to the database. This is why I need to have a batch size diff from commit interval.

Comment: From your answer and my research, it is clear that the `JdbcBatchItemWriter` does not allow a custom batch-size. I have accepted your answer and posted a new [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58534924/spring-batch-write-a-list-to-a-database-table-using-a-custom-batch-size). Please take a look and provide your inputs.